# Auto recognize PCL point cloud type

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I follow the tutorial of the PCL website.

It use the point cloud type below:

```
pcl::PCLPointCloud2
```

I wonder if I can auto recognize the type of the point cloud like `pcl::PointXYZ`, `pcl::PointXYZNomrals`then convert them automatically to the function I would like to use? Is there any function in `pcl::PCLPointCloud2` able to find the type of the point cloud?

Like this:

```
if(POINT_CLOUD_WITHOUT_NORMALS)
    pcl::fromPointCloud2(pointcloud2, *cloud_without_normal);
else if(POINT_CLOUD_WITH_NORMALS)
    pcl::fromPointCloud2(pointcloud2, *cloud_normal);
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to recognize the type of the cloud by using `pcl::getFieldsList`

This returns the type of a cloud in the format of `std::string`.

Ex.

`pcl::PointXYZ` returns **x y z**

`pcl::PointXYZNormal` returns **x y z normal_x normal_y normal_z curvature**